# Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, debugging

I try to forecast few step ahead. And I encountered the problem of 
    **Index exceeds matrix dimensions** at
 volrv(index2,index1)=sum(rv1m(index2-index1+1:index2,1));
Although I have checked the matrix size is ok. I dont understand why. HELP please

```
load sp100_88_03_for.txt;
[y]=sp100_88_03_for;
T=3585; % In-Sample: 1/1/1988-9/28/2001
N = size(y,1);
dataf = 100*(log(y(2:N))-log(y(1:N-1))); % data to be forecast
N = N - 1; % You loose 1 obs'n in taking the lag
clear y;
%ERRORS
datafm = mean(dataf); %mean of all the sample for the forecast error
errors = dataf - datafm; % errors
errors2 = (dataf(T:N)-datafm).^2; % vector with squared errors
% Loading Realized Volatilities
load real_vol_adj.txt
RV_adj = real_vol_adj;
rv1m = RV_adj(:,1);
rv5m = RV_adj(:,2);
clear real_vol*;
clear RV_adj*;
% Calculating the proxy for the volatility process
volr2 = []; % volatilities from sum of squared daily returns
volrv = []; % volatilities from sum of daily realized volatilities
volrd = []; % volatilities from d-day period returns (d=1,2,...,22)
rsquared=(dataf(T:N)-mean(dataf(T:N))).^2;
volr2(:,1)=rsquared;
volrv(:,1)=rv1m;
for index1=2:22;
          volr2(1:index1-1,index1) = 0;
          volrv(1:index1-1,index1) = 0;
      for index2=index1:N-T+1
          volr2(index2,index1)=sum(rsquared(index2-index1+1:index2,1));
          volrv(index2,index1)=sum(rv1m(index2-index1+1:index2,1));
      end
end
```

**Error in ==> 
        volrv(index2,index1)=sum(rv1m(index2-index1+1:index2,1));**

Thanks

Comment: How about adding some debug output?  Before the offending line, print the values of `index2-index1+1:index2` and `size(rsquared)`.  This should immediately tell you where it is out of bounds, and you can trace back to figure out why.

Comment: I tried. But there is no mistake i think. Thanks for suggesting

Comment: Your statement is in clear contradiction with the error. Use `dbstop if error` or provide size details right before it errors.

Comment: i found out that left hand side equal 0, while right hand side equal 2.3. Thats why it shows the message. But I dont know why the left handside is 0

Comment: i did everythings. My professors gave it to me but still cant find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, your code breaks in line `30`.
So, I set a [`breakpoint`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-182) in that line and did

```
size(rsquared)

ans = 

    1  3585
```

However, you try to access `rsquared(1:2,1)`which in this case gives an

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

error message.

One quick fix could be:

```
volr2(index2,index1)=sum(rsquared(1,index2-index1+1:index2));
```

But that depends on your specific problem.
After that fix, the code worked without error for me.